# pwnlib.exception.PwnlibException: kernel architecture must be specified

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles, elf, 32-bit, pwntools

Hi so I have a 32 bit little endian executable on Intel arch so I used context.binary for that and tried context.arch = vax to resolve this issue but both are not working what should I do?
Code below:

```
from pwn import *

context.binary = binary = ELF("./vuln3-32")
rop = ROP(binary)
rop.execve('/bin/sh')
```

Very simple and should just call execve to open a shellcode. Any ideas? I will just try different context.archs for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `context.kernel` to give pwntools more informations on your running environment : is it a 32-bit ELF executing on a 32-bit or on a 64-bit kernel ?

You can see it in "pwnlib/rop/srop.py" :

```py
    @LocalContext
    def __init__(self):
        if context.kernel is None and context.arch == 'i386':
            log.error("kernel architecture must be specified")

        self.arch = context.arch
        self.endian = context.endian
        self._regs = [self.registers[i] for i in sorted(self.registers.keys())]
        self.update({r:0 for r in self._regs})
        self.size = len(bytes(self))
        self.update(defaults[self.arch])

        if context.arch == 'i386' and context.kernel == 'amd64':
            self.update(defaults['i386_on_amd64'])
```